# In Magento 2, How can I add a custom class to a SPECIFIC customer navigation item, ie "Company Structure"

Tags: magento2, css

In Magento 2.3 I'm trying to add a custom class instead of **nav item** to a specific menu item.  In my case it's "Company Structure".  A perfect solution would have each item with a distinct class like "nav item companystructure", but if I can just do one I'll take it.

I know how to modify ALL items in customer_account.xml, but I can't figure out how to change the `<li>` class for a specific item.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below file which is loaded in menu code :

```
app\code\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu.php
```